# can I use vertex alpha to blend 2 textures?

Tags: node-editor

I'm currently using the newest build of Blander 2.79 which has the vertex alpha support. Is there any way to use the vertex alpha to blend between 2 textures?

I have this node set up, but the seperate RGB node doesn't have an alpha output, and I can't seem to find any other node that will allow me to get the vert alpha info from the attribute node.

[image]

It has to be the alpha and not any other vertex colour channel as that's what our in-game shader uses. 
any help would be greatly appreciated.

cheers

edit: obviously the second Diffuse BSDF would be plugged into the Mix Shader but I must have unplugged it by accident before taking the screenshot

Comment: This is a long shot; have you tried the Factor output of the Attribute node?

Comment: Yes, it didn't work. it just displays the 1 texture.